# Expected value of random variables' sample means

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, variance, expected-value

I'm given $Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_i$ i.i.d. random variables that are $N(1, \sigma ^2)$.

I am asked to obtain the $E \big[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i^2 \big]$

What I did is equate what's in brackets to the mean of $Y_i^2$ so...

MY SOLUTION:

$E\big[\overline {Y_i^2} \big]$

$E\big[\overline {Y_i^2} \big]$  = $V\big[\overline Y_i \big] + E\big[\overline Y_i \big]^2$

Then of course $V\big[\overline Y_i \big]$ = $\sigma ^2 /n$ and $E\big[\overline Y_i \big]^2$ = 1

so $E\big[\overline {Y_i^2} \big]$  = $\frac{\sigma ^2} {n}  + 1$

BUT, the solutions say that the answer is simply ${\sigma ^2}   + 1$ since they extracted the sum from the intial expected value given so:

THE CORRECT SOLUTION:

$E \big[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i^2 \big]$ = 
$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}E \big[  Y_i^2 \big]$ = $E \big[  Y_i^2 \big]$ = $E\big[ Y_i^2 \big]$  = $V\big[ Y_i \big] + E\big[ Y_i \big]^2$ = $\sigma +1$

Is $E \big[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i^2 \big] $ not equal to $E\big[\overline {Y_i^2} \big]$? If not why not
? My main concern is I do not understand why my solution is wrong

Answer (score 1):

$$
\mathbb{E} \left[\frac 1 n  \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2\right] = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E} \left[Y_i^2\right] = \mathbb{E} Y_1^2 = \sigma^2 + 1.
$$
The first equation is due to linearity of expected value operator, second one is due to i.i.d. of $Y_i$s and the third is the formula for variance.

What is wrong with your solution: 
You write $\overline{Y_i^2}$ but instead it should be $(\overline{Y_i})^2$

Comment: I understand why the solution works and what you did. What I don't understand is why my solution is wrong

Comment: @ajdawg it should be $(\overline{Y_i})^2$ instead of  $\overline{Y_i^2}$